# как починить mysql-server?

Tags: mysql, kubuntu, lemp

пытаюсь установить LEMP.

не могу запустить mysql-server на kubuntu18.04.

попытка запуска:

```
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

проверка статуса:

```
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-14 16:40:40 MSK; 7s ago
  Process: 9988 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 14 16:40:40 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```